# android: how to get display resolution in native code

Tags: android, screen

Is it possible in android to get display dimensions in the native code?

I see that there are EGL related function:

`EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);`

`surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, engine->app->window, NULL);`

`eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);`

`eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);`

But I need dimension without creating any surface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android get screen size via C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131429/android-get-screen-size-via-c)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the window size while processing the `APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW` "app command" like this in your native activity:

```
static void engine_handle_cmd(struct android_app* app, int32_t cmd) {
    struct engine* engine = (struct engine*)app->userData;
    switch (cmd) {
    case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
        if (engine->app->window != NULL) {
            int width = ANativeWindow_getWidth(engine->app->window);
            int height = ANativeWindow_getHeight(engine->app->window);
        }
```

Check out `main.c` in the `native-activity` sample NDK project if you want to know how to set up the `engine` struct & the `engine_handle_cmd` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the relevant code taken from the Google source for screen capture http://code.google.com/p/androidscreenshot/source/browse/trunk/Binary/screenshot.c?r=3

the vinfo structure contains fields xres and yres.

`int framebufferHandle = -1;`

```
struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
framebufferHandle = open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDONLY);
if(framebufferHandle < 0) 
{
    printf("failed to open /dev/graphics/fb0\n");
    // handle error
}

if(ioctl(framebufferHandle, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) < 0) 
{
    printf("failed to open ioctl\n");
    // handle error
}
fcntl(framebufferHandle, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above code won't work on majority of devices since access to /dev/graphics is restricted

Answer (score -1):

if you're looking for the pixel values height_pixels and width_pixels are probs what you're looking for. See the developer docs for more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: oh sorry I don't have experience with the NDK :(