# Writing to an Android display from ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, surfaceview, framebuffer

Writing directly to the framebuffer no longer works. Is there anyway to write to the display in the NDK?  I might use ANativeWindow but that requires an existing surface. Is there a better way? Or is the only way to create a surface, natively, and then use ANativeWindow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display is owned by SurfaceFlinger and Hardware Composer, so unless you're planning to halt the Android framework you will need to work through them.  (See the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) for more details.)

If you're developing a stand-alone command that is running as "shell" or "root", and you don't mind using non-public interfaces, you can just ask SurfaceFlinger for a window and draw on that.  As of 5.0 "Lollipop" the old GLES tests were updated to work this way.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472003/android-opengles-cmdline-tool-getting-maindisplay-resolution/27472366#27472366) for pointers; the San Angeles demo is illustrative.

If you're developing a regular app, you have to create a Surface and render to that through ANativeWindow.  Regular apps aren't allowed exclusive access to the displays.

Comment: Great answer. That answers my question and any subsequent questions I had!